# Php laravel data display value instead of name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

A table row displayed data value instead of the *department* names. I tried to do some reading at the laravel website and found that this topic is under Eloquent:Relationships and thus have tried to implement it on my models. If I just use {{ $data->department }}, that allows me to retrieve the data but I got the value, an integer that corresponds to the *department* category on the table. But when I use {{ $data->Department->department }}, it got me an error Undefined property: stdClass::$DepartmentHowever, it seems like it's not working out. I think that I got some gaps in my knowledge.  Please help. In a very tight schedule, I need to complete this project by tomorrow.

Data that I want to retrieve

```
<tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
                        @foreach($info as $data)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                <div class="flex items-center">
                                    <div class="flex-shrink-0 h-10 w-10">
                                        {{ $data -> staff_id }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                <div class="text-sm text-gray-900">{{ $data -> name }}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
                                <div class="text-sm text-gray-900">{{ $data -> email }}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                                {{ $data->Department->department }}
                            </td>
                            @endforeach
                            @if (auth()->user())
                            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"> <a href="/profile"> View profile </a></td>
                            @endif
                            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"></td>
                            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"></td>
                            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"></td>
                            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"> <a href="/profile/edit/{{ Auth::user()->id }}">Edit </a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

To use **Department**, I created a new function and put it on *all* my 4 models, to see that it may works. But in this case it didn't.

```
public function Department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class, 'department');
    }
```

The page of the data that I shown previously is in AdminController and the route is,

```
Route::get('staffrecord', [AdminController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth');
```

$data query in AdminController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $info = DB::table('users')->get();
        return view('staffrecord', compact('info'));
    }
}
```

Do I have to create a new model that corresponds to AdminController ? If it is, how should I name it ?

Comment: Can we get a screenshot of what you are getting? have you tried echoing department object?

Comment: i got an error Undefined property: stdClass::$Department. i updated this in my post

Comment: @Mashtan updated my post for more info

Comment: show us your `$data` query in the controller

Comment: @didenetahi i updated in my post. have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call the relationship with the query:

```
$info = User::with('department')->get() ;
```

this should work.

Comment: it workss ! any explanation why it works ? any differences between DB::table('user') and User::with() ?

Comment: i called the relationship using `with` to avoid the n+1 problem.

Comment: by doing that, i get all the infos with their associated departments. In your case- your code above-  you could do `$data->Department()->department`. Notice that i add ( ) to call the relationship, instead of showing the attribute.

Comment: but i didn't recommend it, because for each info you have, you will execute a query to the db engine. `with` is very useful when you want to avoid that.

Comment: if you get what you were looking for, mark your question as answered, feel free to ask for more explanation :)